# How to break up a sentence (String) into a list ([String])?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
    realWord :: String -> String
    realWord s = if elem (map toLower s) ["the","a","of","in","at"] then "" else (map toLower s)
```

This is to test if a string like "the godfather" contains any number of trivial words such as "the". However, when I put "the godfather" into the function, clearly it gives that this string isn't contained in the list, and spits the sentence out again.

How do I break the sentence "the godfather" into a list of words that I can test individually and then put back together again in a sentence?

My desired output for input "the godfather" is "godfather".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Prelude functions [`words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3awords) and [`unwords`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aunwords):

```
realWord = unwords . filter (`notElem` trivial) . words . toLower
    where trivial = ["the","a","of","in","at"]
```

Comment: This is also a good case where [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) can help you find the standard Prelude functions you want, often if you search for the desired function type (`:: String -> [String]` in this case) `words` is pretty close to the top of the search results ([here](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+String+-%3E+%5BString%5D).)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, DRY:

```
realWord s 
    | s' `elem` trivial  = ""
    | otherwise          = s'
  where trivial = ["the","a","of","in","at"]
        s' = map toLower s
```

So. The problem is, you're not deconstructing the string in any way. What you're trying to do is matching on something and "consuming & throwing away" it when found – that's actually a very basic subtask of *parsing*.

For this problem, Niklas' solution is probably the best, but to make this more general it's simple enough to use [one of the "big weapons"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec):

```
import Text.Parsec

extractRealWord :: Parsec String u String
extractRealWord = do
      skipMany . choice
         . map (\w -> string w >> many (oneOf ",. !?\n"))
            $ ["the", "a", "of", "in", "at"]
                            >>= \w@(f:r) -> [w, toUpper f : r]
      many . oneOf $ ['a' .. 'z'] ++ ['A' .. 'Z']
```

To be used e.g.

> Prelude Text.Parsec Data.Char> runP extractRealWord ()[] "the godfather"
>   Right "godfather"